# Display data from other table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Sorry for beginner's question. I would like to ask you about ms sql and asp.net. I've got 2 tables - Album and Artist. I want to display all albums after clickiing Artist Details. Could you please let me know how to display for example Title in Artits's display? Please find below models from my application

```
    public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }

}

    public class Album
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

Below views/artists/details.cshtml

```
@model AlbumStore.Models.Artist

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
<h4>Artist</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>
</dl>
</div>
<div>
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.ArtistId">Edit</a> |
<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You would use a query with a join in it. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/